# Android - Toggle status bar transparency between Fragments in a Viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, transparency, statusbar

I've exhausted essentially every post I've found regarding changing the status bar color programmatically, but none of them touch on this specific case.

I have an Activity that contains a ViewPager and a BottomNavigationView. The ViewPager holds three Fragments and the BottomNavigationView moves between them with smoothscroll turned off.

As the first of the three Fragments is a map, I'd like the status bar to be transparent when the first Fragment is shown, but revert back to its opaque color on the other two Fragments.

Here's some code that shows how I'm attempting to set and revert the status bar states.

```
private class TabSelectedObserver implements Observer<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer selectedTab) {
        if (selectedTab != null) {
            activityMainBinding.mainPager.setCurrentItem(selectedTab, false);
            switch (selectedTab) {
                case 0:
                    applyTransparentStatusBarTheme();
                    break;
                default:
                    applyOpaqueStatusBarTheme();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void applyTransparentStatusBarTheme() {
    hideSystemUi();
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.transparent));
}

private void applyOpaqueStatusBarTheme() {
    showSystemUi();
    getWindow().setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.rippallete_700));
}

private void hideSystemUi() {
    // Set flags for hiding status bar and navigation bar

    mSystemUiVisibility = mSystemUiVisibility
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mSystemUiVisibility);
}

private void showSystemUi() {
    // Reset flags for hiding status bar and navigation bar
    mSystemUiVisibility = mSystemUiVisibility
            & ~View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mSystemUiVisibility);
}
```

[Here's a gif showing the behavior I end up with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF9J9.gif)

Every thing I tried with `fitSystemWindows` didn't produce the result I wanted.

If anyone has any suggestions for how you would give each Fragment an individual status bar color, with 1 being transparent, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you're setting the status bar colours based on the position of whatever tab you have selected you could do something similar to this:

```
private void updateStatusBarColour(int tabPosition) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = getWindow();
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

        switch (tabPosition) {
            case FIRST_TAB:
            case SECOND_TAB:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    mRootView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
                }
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryLight));
                break;
            case THIRD_TAB:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    mRootView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
                }
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                break;
            case FOURTH_TAB:
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    mRootView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
                }
                window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorDarkTan));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I call `setSystemUiVisibility` on `mRootView`, where `mRootView` is the root parent view containing the ViewPager (or whatever is the root layout of your containing Activity). The call specifically sets the theme of the status bar so that status bar items (like the battery symbol) can be visible on dark or light background depending on what colour you end up setting.

Comment: how can I reset it again to orignal one?